# Using app engine java image api with eclipse + dev server?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the image api for google app engine java. I've uploaded an image using my dev server + eclipse, but trying to use any of the image api does not work. This is explained by the exception which is thrown:

> Jul 6, 2010 5:28:02 PM com.google.appengine.api.images.dev.LocalImagesService init
>   WARNING: No image reader found for format "ico". An ImageIO plugin must be installed to use this format with the DevAppServer.
>
> Jul 6, 2010 5:28:02 PM com.google.appengine.api.images.dev.LocalImagesService init
>   WARNING: No image reader found for format "tif". An ImageIO plugin must be installed to use this format with the DevAppServer.

is there a plugin we can use locally in the dev server, or is our only option to run it live on app engine to see if it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to work with 'ico' and 'tif' images. Neither of these are supported on App Engine - only JPG, PNG and GIF.

Comment: Can you provide a prooflink, please?

Comment: This answer is out of date. From Google's docs: 

The service accepts image data in the JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated GIF), BMP, TIFF and ICO formats.

It can return transformed images in the JPEG, WEBP and PNG formats. If the input format and the output format are different, the service converts the input data to the output format before performing the transformation.